# What are these codes doing? (paste function,setnames)

Tags: r, paste, col

I am confused about the following codes are doing:

```
X2_X26 <- paste("X", 2:26, sep = "")

portf_exret <- paste("excess_return_portfolio", 1:25, sep ="")

X27_X51 <- paste("X", 27:51, sep = "")

logsize_p <- paste("logsize_portfolio", 1:25, sep = "")

setnames(datafile, old = 'X1', new = 'market_exret')

setnames(datafile, old = X2_X26, new = portf_exret)

setnames(datafile, old = X27_X51, new = logsize_p)
```

1. For the first line, is it saying: create X2,X3...X26(each of them are seperate columns), and then store it into a dataframe called"X2_X26"?
   Then, the setnames function says change the name of X2_X26 dataframe to portf_exret dataframe, nothing else change?
2. As we have not previously defined 'X1', for the setnames(datafile, old='X1), is it refering to the first column in the dataframe by default?
3. What are these code doing? Why we need to change the column from 2:26 to 1:25?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: In the first use of `setnames`, note that "X1" is in quotes, which means the function is being passed the string "X1", not an object named X1. This code appears to rename a large number of generically named columns with more descriptive names.

Answer (score 0):

- `datafile` is frame of class `data.table`
- it has columns named `"X1", "X2", "X3"... "X51"` (and possibly additional columns)
- The lines `X2_X26 <- paste("X", 2:26, sep = "")` and `X27_X51 <- paste("X", 27:51, sep = "")` are creating vectors, each of length 25, containing the strings `"X2", "X2"..."X26"` and `"X27", "X28", ... "X51"`, respectively
- The line assigning to `portf_xret` is creating a string vector of length 25, that will eventually replace the first set of generic columns `X2` through `X26`. This string vector looks like this `"excess_return_portfolio1", "excess_return_porfolio2" ... "excess_return_portfolio25"`
- The line assigning to `logsize_p` is creating a string vector of length 25, that will eventually replace the second set of generic columns `X27` through `X51`. This string vector looks like this `"logsize_portfolio1", "logsize_portfolio2" ... "logsize_portfolio25"`
- Finally, `data.table::setnames()` is called three times, each time feeding `datafile` (the object for which the columns should be renamed), the old names, and the new names.  These three lines could also have been combined like this: `setnames(datafile, old=c("X1", X2_X26, X27_X51), new=c("market_exret", portf_xret, logsize_p))`

Comment: Can you please confirm whether a vecor is put like a column or is put like a row? For example, is X2, X3... X51 are displayed in the same row, or X2 is at the first row, X3 is ar the second row and so on(at the same time, they're in the same column)? Thank you.

Comment: Neither. There is nothing in this code that changes the data in the `datafile` (neither rows nor columns). The entire code is about changing the names of the columns.  The first four lines create vectors that summarize old (current) and new names. The `setnames` lines use `data.table::setnames()` function to replace the old names with the new names.